# Removing columns in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R?

Tags: r, polygon, vector, data-frame, remove

My spatial polygon data frame (SPDF) contains too many columns (variables) and I want to remove most of the columns entirely.

I know how to do this with a regular data frame in R, but I am unsure how to do this when dealing with object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the syntax `object_ name[,-(1:5)]` to remove columns 1 to 5 or `object_name[,-c(1,5)]` to drop columns 1 and 5. See the example below (with comments):

```
require(maptools)

#load shapefile from maptools package to make a reproducible example.
xx <- readShapeSpatial(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
                   IDvar="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))

class(xx) #check the object class
#[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
#attr(,"package")
#[1] "sp"

head(xx@data,3) #print first three rows from the slot 'data'

       AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID      NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
      0.111     1.392  1904    1904  Alamance 37001  37001        1  4672    13
      0.066     1.070  1950    1950 Alexander 37003  37003        2  1333     0
      0.061     1.231  1827    1827 Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0

      NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79
         1243  5767    11    1397
          128  1683     2     150
           10   542     3      12

xxx <- xx[,-(1:5)] #remove columns 1 to 5

head(xxx@data,3) #print the subsetted data frame

     FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79
     37001  37001        1  4672    13    1243  5767    11    1397
     37003  37003        2  1333     0     128  1683     2     150
     37005  37005        3   487     0      10   542     3      12
```

To use the names of columns, you can implement Joris Meys' solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame), which consists in creating a list of names and using it to drop the columns.

For example:

```
drops <- c("AREA","PERIMETER") # list of col names
xxx <- xx[,!(names(xx) %in% drops)] #remove columns "AREA" and "PERIMETER"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one alternative using the [select](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/select) function from package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

SPDF@data <- SPDF@data %>% 
select(1, 3) #keeps column 1 and column 3 in the spdf object.
```

Comment: It makes me nervious operating on the @data slot using packages or functions not specifically designed for spatial objects. This is why there is a special version of merge, The base version of merge screws up the row names and breaks the relationships between the attributes and features.

Answer (score 0):

The following command also does the trick, but you must know your column numbers:

```
temp<-df[c(1:6,99:103)]
```